# Redux remove reducer filter method not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui

I'm trying to remove an item from an array using the filter method like so:

```
removeDisplate: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
  console.log(action.payload);
  state.map((item) => {
    console.log(item.name);
  });
  state.filter((item) => item.name !== action.payload);
},
```

And calling it from my frontend like so:

```
{cart.map((displate, index) => {
  return (
    <Card
      sx={{
        minHeight: "150px",
        display: "flex",
        padding: "10px",
        gap: "10px",
        backgroundColor: "black",
        margin: "10px",
        position: "relative",
      }}
      key={index}
    >
      <CloseIcon
        sx={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "10px",
          right: "10px",
          color: "red",
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}
        onClick={() => handleRemoveDisplate(displate.name)}
      />
    </Card>
  );
})}
```

Both the payload and the name of the item in state are the same as per the console logs, but it's still not removing it from the array, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` doesn't mutate the array it operates over, it returns a ***new*** array with elements failing the predicate callback removed. In the slice reducer you can just return the result of filtering the current state as the next state value.

```
removeDisplate: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
  return state.filter((item) => item.name !== action.payload);
},
```

Additionally, since you are mutating this array you'll want to ***not*** use the array index as the React key. Use a value that is more intrinsic to the data you are mapping, like `id` properties.

Example:

```
{cart.map((displate, index) => {
  return (
    <Card
      sx={{
        minHeight: "150px",
        display: "flex",
        padding: "10px",
        gap: "10px",
        backgroundColor: "black",
        margin: "10px",
        position: "relative",
      }}
      key={displate.id} // <-- or any unique property among sibling elements
    >
      <CloseIcon
        sx={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "10px",
          right: "10px",
          color: "red",
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}
        onClick={() => handleRemoveDisplate(displate.name)}
      />
    </Card>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Amazing and informative answer, thanks so much! Could you explain why having a unique key value is so important? It's working fine rn, when will it become an issue?

Comment: @ether Using good React keys is important because it helps identify React components during the reconciliation process. See [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). When using the index as a key *an* issue that usually manifests is that you remove an element from the middle of the array... all the elements after that shift up an index. When mapped the old "i + 1"-th element is now the "i"-th element. The key is the same so React bails on rerendering the element, and now that the array is 1 element shorter the last element is not rendered.